# Why does this for loop keep incrementing when the condition is false?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, infinite-loop

I have the following loop:

```
for (let i = 100; i > 1; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    i = 1;
}
```

When i enters the for loop again it is 1 so the condition i > 1 is false but it keeps looping infinitely and printing 2.

I also tried with i !== 1 and/or ++i but the same thing happens.

Same behaviour in other languages:

```
for (int i = 100; i > 1; i++) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    i = 1;
}
```

Output:

```
...
2
2
2
...
```

As far as I know the increment operation should not happen if the condition is false.

Comment: The last expression in the loop header increments the variable `i` to 2. The increment expression is evaluated **before** the condition test is made.

Comment: The order of the loop is: initialize, check, execute body, increment, check ...

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of a `for` loop is:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

(quotting from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), the `final-expression` is:

"*An expression to be evaluated at the **end of each loop iteration**. This occurs **before** the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to update or increment the counter variable.*"

Your statement block ends with setting `i` to 1. **Before** entering the next iteration, the loop's `final-expression` is performing the increment, thus setting `i` to 2 before repeating the statement block.

Answer (score 1):

So what I understand from Dave's answer is that what happens inside the for loop is:

```
for (let i = 100; i > 1;) {
    console.log(i);
    i = 1;
    i++;
}
```

and not:

```
for (let i = 100; i > 1;) {
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    i = 1;
}
```

Comment: Exactly, the final expression (`i++`  in your case) is executed before the next evaluation of the condition (`i > 1`).